# Is it correct to a total Cronbach´s alpha analysis to a tridimensional scale?

Tags: reliability, psychometrics, psychology, cronbachs-alpha

There´s a statement that says that Cronbach´s alpha assumes unidimensionality. In that sense, is it correct to calculate a global alpha? I mean, by including all 3 dimensions, and not by separating them.

Comment: For example, I have a questionnaire measuring one construct, "math IQ", and another questionnaire measuring "verbal IQ". Results of the two scales correlate weakly. May I compute alpha on the combined set of items from both constructs? Yes I may but that implies I'm treating it as single construct "math-verbal IQ". Do you think it is reasonable? I doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you want to use Mcdonald's omega (hierarchical) this tells you the underlying reliability of a multidimensional scale (Cronbach's doesn't). It can  be done using the Psych package in R https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/index.html

Indeed Cronbach's alpha is often used to report overall reliability of a multidimensional scale. This is problematic as alpha increases with the number of items so what you tend to get is subscales with lower alphas and then a full scale alpha which is higher than the two. Obviously, this doesn't make sense (how can two lower alphas on subscales measuring something different add up to a higher alpha). This is incredibly common to see in papers.